# Automatically add users to API Manager

Tags: wso2

I am looking for a way to automatically add users to WSO2 API Manager. I have a basic install with the H2 database, but someday I might move to postgres or something like that. What is the best way to add users from say a script?

Answer (score 0):

In Carbon products (APIM, IS), All user store operations can be exposed via web services. External application can use these web services to add/delete/update/get  in to user store users and groups. Please note, H2 is not recommended for products`

1. REST web service according to the SCIM provisioning specification.
2. SOAP based Web service. You can find more detail from [here](http://soasecurity.org/2013/12/10/user-role-management-with-wso2-identity-server-apis/)